# VS2015/DNX building Microsoft.Framework.Logging from github results in testing error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, xunit, dnx

So I have my VS2015 Enterprise installed.  I grab the latest Microsoft.Framework.Logging from [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging), load the solution and build it.

After it restores all the dependent packages it does seem to build OK but then I get this error on the test:

``` Starting  Microsoft.Framework.TestHost [C:\Users\dan_000\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin\dnx.exe --appbase "D:\code\DanForks\Logging\test\Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Test" Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost --port 1388 Microsoft.Framework.TestHost --port 5651]
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.Framework.TestHost'. Available commands: run, test.
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ThrowEntryPointNotfoundException(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, Exception innerException)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List``1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework) ```

When I run the same command in a command prompt with DNX_TRACE=1, I get:

``` Test" Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost --port 1388 test --port 1462
The servicing index file at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DNX\Servicing\index.txt does not exist or could not be opened.
Loaded module: dnx.clr.dll
Found export: CallApplicationMain
Information: [DomainManager] Using Desktop CLR v4.5.1
Information: [Bootstrapper] Runtime Framework: DNX,Version=v4.5.1
Information: [DefaultHost]: Project path: D:\code\DanForks\Logging\test\Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Test
Information: [DefaultHost]: Project root: D:\code\DanForks\Logging
Information: [DefaultHost]: Packages path: C:\Users\dan_000\.dnx\packages
Information: [DependencyWalker]: Walking dependency graph for 'Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Test DNX,Version=v4.5.1'.
Information: [WalkContext]: Graph walk stage 1 took in 28ms
Information: [DependencyWalker]: Graph walk took 31ms.
Information: [ServicingIndex]: Servicing index not found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DNX\Servicing\index.txt
Information: [WalkContext]: Populate took 15ms
Information: [DependencyWalker]: Resolved dependencies for Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Test in 49ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=xunit.runner.aspnet
Information: [NuGetAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=xunit.runner.aspnet in 5ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=xunit.runner.utility.AspNet, Version=99.99.99.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Information: [NuGetAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=xunit.runner.utility.AspNet, Version=99.99.99.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null in 1ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=xunit.abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c
Information: [NuGetAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=xunit.abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c in 1ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Information: [NuGetAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null in 1ms
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Xunit.Runner.AspNet.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List``1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework) ```

My solution DNX versions for all the projects is 1.0.0-beta6.

I'm not extremely familiar with how the xunit stuff all works.  I figure I have some sort of runtime mismatch somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the dependency changes which breaks xunit runner. I think you have to wait xunit update reference or code to address the changes. Also, different version of xunit target different dnx as well. Make sure update xunit to xUnit.net 2.1 Beta 4
http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html